# What does #Soreadytohelp mean?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page, site-promotion, site-specific

I saw that some of the user profiles contain `#Soreadytohelp`.

Do they simply mean something?

Comment: [Example 1](https://askubuntu.com/users/2664/emmys). [Example 2](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/222264/tausun). [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213136/bob-jarvis-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It was a contest from 2015 to celebrate the [10 million questions in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey).

They asked to share your experience about Stack Overflow in Twitter with the `#SOreadytohelp` hashtag.

In case you are not using Twitter:

> Not a fan of teh twitters? No problem. Just add #SOreadytohelp to your "About Me" on your profile page.

So many of them added the #SOreadytohelp in their profile.

[image: SOReadyToHelp contest announcement]

Comment: Did anyone actually got a shirt out of this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: From [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303721/)'s comments, few of them received and most of them not received the T-Shirts.

Comment: @Arulkumar thanks, though it might have just took longer, asked one of them if he got it by now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think I got a swag pack related to one of these things. Including one of those shirts.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek nice, question is how many others? And how many didn't get to this day? :/

Comment: What's a *teh twitter*?

Comment: The more relevant MSO post: [Who are the winners in the #SOreadytohelp t-shirt drawing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303721/1478931)